# Why Wordpress is so slow with even just initial lightweight template?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have just installed WordPress on current version from WordPress.org v4.9.5. I did not install just anything but the basic template that comes out of the box from the WordPress itself.

I am trying to swipe between pages both in admin panel and in the site, but it takes something around to 3 seconds for pages to reload.

Those pages are blank.

I am using my own VPS, which is very strong for such a task.
Good connection to Internet,
My server has lots of capacity SSD and etc..
When running HTML site or PHP site, I can load huge content in a page and it will take only 0.3 seconds to load (if I am organize the document properly).
My VPS PHP current version is 7.
4 Cores, 16GB of Ram, every other site in my VPS is just speed as light.

What leads me to think, does WordPress is not organized well from its core? 
I did not include even a single plugin.

Later on, I have tried install some W3 Super cache plugin and maybe one or more like this, but nothing helps.

When installed Woocommerce, the WordPress even became slower.

I have searched at Google but seems that all of the things that people are say to do or not to do are fully accomplished by the environment I created for that task.

Simply WordPress is super slow by its core?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, WordPress is very slow. This is a reason for the massive move towards updating with the [WordPress REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) - since you are then interacting with JSON data in endpoints via HTTP (specifically GET requests), your updates are near instantaneous. The only time I have had WordPress run efficiently in the way you described was a clean install with a local copy and server.

In short if you are unsatisfied with WordPress's speed I would recommend looking into the REST API.

Comment: This is true, I forgot to mention WP Rest is built into WordPress [as of 4.7](https://v2.wp-api.org/).

Comment: I know what is REST API and I am working with this. But I do not know how it goes related with WordPress, is there a different version or bundle of WordPress out there that can replace the current one?